# Passing JSON arguments (not simple strings) to jq

Tags: bash, jq

How do I pass in bash variables into a jq `--arg` parameter?

All I can get to work is this:

```
FINAL_JSON= #some JSON

PAYLOAD=$(echo $FINAL_JSON | jq ' {
"attachments": .
} ')
```

What's bothering me is that `echo $FINAL_JSON` thing.  I should be able to pass in variables in `jq`??

```
PAYLOAD=$(jq -n --arg attach "$FINAL_JSON" '{ 
"attachments":$attach
}')
```

But all that does is pass the JSON in as a string.  Without quotes `"` around the `$FINAL_JSON` I get this error:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected $end
{1 compile error
```

Comment: in general, always quote your `echo` --> `echo "$FINAL_JSON"`

Comment: yea, I don't even wanna `echo` tho

Comment: What's the meaning of `FINAL_JSON=$(jq -n '[]')` ? It simply returns a literal `[]` . What means `# add stuff to FINAL_JSON` ?

Comment: I'm populating `$FINAL_JSON` as it pulls down data from various sources like `Github` `Hockey` and `Pivotal`.  The JSON is all formatted correctly - that's not the issue.  I want to know how to properly pass `$FINAL_JSON` as an `--arg` to `jq`

Comment: I'm still not able to get your question. Can you add one self-contained example which shows how do you *not* want to do it and one self-contained example which you want it to look like? (The latter can be pseudo code or course, since you don't have it already)

Comment: This is much too large and sprawling a question. If you could do more work to isolate the place where you're having trouble, it would be easier for folks to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for hints.

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `jq . <<< $FINAL_JSON`.

Comment: @cmbuckley, needs more quotes. `<<<"$FINAL_JSON"`.

Comment: BTW -- all-caps variable names are bad practice. See the fourth paragraph for http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html for POSIX environment variable naming practices, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a single namespace.\

Comment: ...so the issue is that you want to pass things in with `--arg`, *and parse them as JSON*? That's doable; I'll need to glance at the manual to remember how.

Comment: I've tried to make the title more useful. We have lots of questions here about using jq from bash; a title should make it clear what makes a specific question distinct, so folks looking through the search listings can tell at a glance if it applies to them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, wording/verbage isn't always my best suit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple transformation of your working code (also moving to lower-case variable names, as per convention for variable names not reserved for shell or system use):

```
payload=$(jq -n --argfile attach <(printf '%s\n' "$final_json") '{ 
"attachments":$attach
}')
```

I'm sticking with `--argfile` here since it parses the file's contents as JSON; using `--arg` wouldn't have that effect.

The `<(...)` syntax is process substitution, which is replaced with a filename for a named pipe or temporary file connected to the content in question.

---

However, you can also use `--arg`, and apply the `fromjson` filter to parse as JSON:

```
payload=$(jq -n --arg attach "$final_json" '{ 
"attachments":$attach|fromjson
}')
```

Comment: `--argjson` is also an option, if you're using 1.5.