# Replace jq predefined variable with number

Tags: jq

`jq` could have predefined variables and replace with `--arg` options. It works well with string. However, I don't know how to replace the variable as number.

```
$jq -n --arg number 3000 '{"number":$number}'
{
  "number": "3000"
}
```

I would like to be able to generate something as following :

```
{
  "number": 3000
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing JSON arguments (not simple strings) to jq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599619/passing-json-arguments-not-simple-strings-to-jq)

Comment: No, the problem is different . This is about how to replace with number type. As `--arg` looks always replace variable as double quote string.

Comment: On the contrary, it's exactly the same. You're asking to convert to numbers, that one converts to whatever is appropriate, whether it's a number, object, whatever. The answer is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, that question does provide a solution. But I still would like to provide an answer for this concrete question.

Comment: I still don't get why you're not seeing it.  Look at the answer... it says to use `fromjson` to convert the string to the appropriate json value.  That's exactly what you're asking for...

Comment: I c. Thanks, that one is nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or:

```
jq -n --arg number 300 '{"number": $number|tonumber}'
```

or (as Jeff pointed out) with jq 1.5:

```
jq -n --argjson number 300 '{"number": $number}'
```

or (with versions of jq after June 26, 2015):

```
jq -n --arg number 300 '{$number} | .number |= tonumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
jq -n --argfile number <(printf '%d' 3000) '{"number":$number}'
```

Or

```
jq -n --arg number 3000 '{"number":$number|fromjson}'
```