# How to pass a variable to jq when the json is in a file?

Tags: environment-variables, jq

I'm trying to recreate [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991616/replace-jq-predefined-variable-with-number) but with storing the json in a file instead of passing the string on the command line. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ cat test.json 
{"number":$number}

$ jq --arg number 3000 test.json 
jq: error: test/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
test.json
jq: 1 compile error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
# That's not json, it's a .jq file
cat test.jq
{"number":$number}

jq -n --arg number 3000 -f test.jq
{
  "number": "3000"
}
```

---

Btw, the above example gives you `"3000"` as a *string*. If you want it to be a number you need to use `--argjson`:

```
jq -n --argjson number 3000 -f test.jq
{
  "number": 3000
}
```

or as a string

```
jq -n --argjson number '"3000"' -f test.jq
{
  "number": "3000"
}
```

Comment: So the correct syntax based on this answer is: `jq -n --arg number 3000 -f test.jq` (without going through an env var)

Comment: I thought you wanted to use a variable. Anyhow, yes, that's the right command.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `jq` here if you use environment variables and substitute them with [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) like this :

```
export number=3000
envsubst < test.json
```

Comment: Note for homebrew users: The gettext formula is "keg-only".  If you have installed gettext, the binary will normally be in a directory having the form /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/VERSION/bin